# rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

sania@sania-Swift-SF314-52:~/library$ rake db:migrate

== 20180407084831 Books: migrating ============================================
-- create_table(:books)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'books' already exists: CREATE TABLE `books` (`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `title` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `price` float, `subject_id` int, `description` text, `created_at` timestamp NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB /home/sania/library/db/migrate/20180407084831_books.rb:4:in `up'
```

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'books' already exists: CREATE TABLE `books` (`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `title` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `price` float, `subject_id` int, `description` text, `created_at` timestamp NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
/home/sania/library/db/migrate/20180407084831_books.rb:4:in `up'

Caused by:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'books' already exists
/home/sania/library/db/migrate/20180407084831_books.rb:4:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

---

This is the content of 20180407084831_books.rb file

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

 def self.up
    create_table :books do |t|
         t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
         t.column :price, :float
         t.column :subject_id, :integer
         t.column :description, :text
         t.column :created_at, :timestamp
      end
   end

   def self.down
      drop_table :books
   end

end
```

---

This is the content of 20180407072616_create_books.rb file

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Please help me with the solution. I am new to rails. I have also tried dropping the db but rakes aborts with the following error**

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError:

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run:

```
    bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
```

---

I am unable to understand the cause of it. Please help me explain. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to down migrate for specific file then you run command with version number like this

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20180407084831 #=> or rails
```

You could use `rails d migration` command to destroy a particular migration file:

```
rails d migration MigrationName
```

[`Active Record Migrations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

**Update**

Look, if your project is now initial step for learning then remove all the project then try from scratch like `rails new project_name -d mysql` it will generate a project with default MySQL database adapter then cd project_name then bundle exec rake db:migrate it will migrate a database if your `database.yml` is ok, I mean username & password. I think it will solve your problem. Firstime it's happening, so don't frustrate keep moving. see guide [`Rails Official Guide`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)  and [`Learn Web Development with Rails - Michael Hartl`](http://railstutorial.org/book) it will help lots of for newbie

Comment: In my case do I need to down migrate or just rollback will do? As I am new to it I really am confused and do not know the utility of both.

Comment: You can drop the database using bundle exec rake db:drop & destroy all migration files, look at first you need to destroy the last migration file which for showing the error, then drop the DB & then read the rails guides active record migration and fresh migrate the DB

Comment: 1. Destroyed the last migration file 2.dropped the database using bundle exec rake db:drop 3. again used these commands :" rails generate migration books" and "rails generate migration subjects" 4. then again migrated using "rake db:migrate". But, again I get the same error as posted in the question.

Comment: Look, if your project is now initial step for learning then remove all the project then try from scratch like **step 2** `rails new project_name -d mysql` it will generate a project with default `mysql` database adapter then `cd project_name` then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` it will migrate a database if your `database.yml` is ok, I mean `username` & `password`. I think it will solve your problem. Firstime it's happening, so don't frustrate keep moving. see guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and https://www.railstutorial.org/book it will help lots of for newbie

Comment: Let me know if any question

Answer (score 0):

Rollback the last migration

```
rake db:rollback
```

Rollback n migrations

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n
```

More info [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Migrations)

If you do not need the last migration and you want to delete it you can 
use @fool-dev answer

Comment: After I have rolled back the migration, do I need to again run the command for migration - rake db:migrate?

Comment: After I run my localhost:3000 this is what I get :       # Raises <tt>ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError</tt> error if any migrations are pending.
      def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
        raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?(connection)
      end

      def load_schema_if_pending!

Comment: Yes, You have to run again db migrate. The `rollback` is just to remove some migration that were already run. In this way you can change the migration file (in case of update/error/changes) and run the db migrate to apply the changes.